# What is the correct way of protecting assignment from non-const-volatile types to const-volatile in meta-programming in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

For example I have a function to implement `null_or`

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto null_or(T *p, U *default_value) ->
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::decay<U>::type,
                                         typename std::decay<T>::type>::value,
                            T *>::type {
  if (p) {
    return p;
  } else {
    return default_value;
  }
}
```

using only `std::decay` will enable `const/volatile type *default_value` to assign into `non-const/non-volatile type *p`.

What is the best way to avoid it?

---

In addition, array types (with extent) like `type default_value[100]` are not assignable to it. How to solve it as well?

---

Can and Cannot examples:

```
  const char *s = nullptr;
  char       *s2 = nullptr;

  const char *hello0 = "hello0";
  std::string hello1 = "hello1";
  char        hello2[] = "hello2";
  char        hello3[100] = "hello3";
  int         hello4[] = {1,2,3,4,5,0};

  const char *ss = nullptr;

  // const char * ==> const char *, OK
  ss = null_or(s, hello0);
  printf("%s\n", ss);

  // std::string ==> const char *, no conversion at all, Bad
  // ss = null_or(s, hello1);
  // printf("%s\n", ss);

  // char [7] ==> const char *, OK
  ss = null_or(s, hello2);
  printf("%s\n", ss);

  // char [100] ==> const char *, OK
  ss = null_or(s, hello3);
  printf("%s\n", ss);

  // int [6] ==> const char *, Bad
  // ss = null_or(s, hello4);
  // printf("%s\n", ss);

  // const char * ==> char *, const pointer stuffs should not be assigned to non consts, Bad
  // ... also, const reference should not be assigned to non const references for some other generic algorithms
  // ss = null_or(s2, hello0);
  // printf("%s\n", ss);

  // std::string ==> char *, no version at all, Bad
  // ss = null_or(s2, hello1);
  // printf("%s\n", ss);

  // char [7] ==> char *, OK
  ss = null_or(s2, hello2);
  printf("%s\n", ss);

  // char [100] ==> char *, OK
  ss = null_or(s2, hello3);
  printf("%s\n", ss);

  // int [6] ==> char *, Bad
  // ss = null_or(s2, hello4);
  // printf("%s\n", ss);
```

---

There're also a lot of other generic algorithms that just need simple concept checking whether the right-hand-side is safe to assign into left-hand-side, so I wonder is there a more general solution to this.

Comment: Sorry, what? Aren't `p` and `default_value` exactly the same type, namely `T*`? Did you mean to make them potentially different types?

Comment: Yes for `type default_value[100]`, because `type[100]` and `type *` are different.

Comment: Can you show a full, self-contained example of code that compiles when you don't want it to (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples already failed when wanted, but according to `null_or` definition.

You may change your declaration to

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto null_or(T *p, U *default_value)
-> typename std::enable_if<std::is_assignable<T*&, U*>::value,
                           T *>::type
```

to SFINAE those error.

Comment: I wonder why is `std::is_assignable<std::vector<int>&, const std::vector<int>&>::value` true? A const reference should not be assigned to non-const reference, or should it?

Comment: @Adam: `GetRef() = GetConstRef;` is valid. with `std::is_constructible` it would be `false`.

Comment: So ... you mean that ```std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4};
  const std::vector<int> &b = a;
  std::vector<int> &c = b;
  c[0] = 1024;``` is valid? But it is not...

Comment: Or am I wrong about ... so, the example I provided was `is_construcible`

Comment: So, here's it ... ```std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,4};
  const std::vector<int> &b = a;
  std::vector<int> &c = a;
  c = b;
  c[0] = 1024;``` Assgining from b (which should protect its values), instantly bypasses its protection, and you may just do anything you want.

Comment: Then there'll be no need for `const_cast` anymore, I'm a little fuzzy ...

Comment: `c = b` doesn't rebind `c` to `b`, but does a copy of `b` content in the c content. (as both alias `a`, it is a self assignment).

Comment: You're right ... `c = b` is a copy assignment. Thx for your patience.